# Undo restoring from backup on iPhone

Tags: ios, restore

I accidentally deleted a downloaded book from iCloud and wanted to restore the book to my phone. So I restored my phone to the last time I synced my phone. In doing so, I have lost all my Apple Watch activity rings data. Is there any way to undo that restore, and bring my phone back to before I restored it? I don't even care about the book anymore. I just want my old activity rings back.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a backup you made of the data you wish to restore, no, the data is lost.